# aws-ec2 - you are not authorized to perform this operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, clojure, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, pallet

I am least familiar with aws etc. What am trying to do is upload a small war file to s3 bucket [using s3-bash](https://github.com/cosmin/s3-bash/) and **PalletOps** at the moment. For that, I have a clojure config file configured as

```clj
(defpallet :default-service
           :vmfest
           :services {:localhost {:provider "localhost"}
                      :vmfest {:provider                "vmfest"
                               :vbox-comm               :ws
                               :default-network-type    :local
                               :default-memory-size     1024
                               :default-local-interface "vboxnet5"}
                      :aws-ec2 {:provider   "aws-ec2"
                                :identity   "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQ"
                                :credential "ATMz1/gerGGFHDh/GFGGFGFGFHFHFHGTUUTUgdgdgdg"}})
```

On aws, I added IAM policy to that user,

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iam:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

While trying to `lein pallet up -P aws-ec2` the cluster with above **config** I get following error,

```
Caused by: org.jclouds.aws.AWSResponseException: request POST
  https://ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ HTTP/1.1 failed with code 403,
        error: AWSError{requestId='c20a65f1-64a1-4d7f-be27-690d495ffd09',
        requestToken='null', code='UnauthorizedOperation', message='You are not
        authorized to perform this operation.', context='{Response=, Errors=}'}
    at org.jclouds.aws.handlers.ParseAWSErrorFromXmlContent.handleError(ParseAWSErrorFromXmlContent.java:77)
    ... 77 more
Subprocess failed
```

I tried simulation at https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp?# as well, but failing even for an action "ListBucket" with error `Implicitly denied (no matching statements found).`.

I may be [missing to configure on aws ec2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/PoliciesOverview.html) but couldn't move further.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need an `s3*` entry in the IAM policy:

Here is an example of a policy that allows uploading only to a specific folder:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Sid": "Stmt13NNNNNNNN000",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/specific-folder/*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow"
    },
{
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Sid": "StmtNNNNNNNNNNN",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
      ],
       "Effect": "Allow"
     }
   ] 
 }
```

It's also worth testing with a crediential in the "power user" pre-built policy (if you can) to rule out such permissions issues.

Comment: Hey Arthur, thanks for the beautiful answer. No idea what worked, after few hours the same thing in my question worked fine. (Heseinberg)